# Bluetooth pairing timed out when not in use after a short time

Tags: kali-linux, bluetooth, bluez

I'm on a Kali (4.18.0-kali3-amd64) and I have an issue with my headsets when I pair them with the internal bluetooth of my computer : it disconnects itself when they're not in use continuously.

```
service bluetooth status
```

Returns when it happens :

```
déc. 20 17:36:56 localhost bluetoothd[1359]: Start: Connection timed out (110)
déc. 20 17:36:56 localhost bluetoothd[1359]: avdtp_start failed
déc. 20 17:36:56 localhost bluetoothd[1359]: Transaction label doesn't match
```

I can redo the pairing but the issue persists and I've search solution about avdtp_start but none are about this specific issue.

```
hciconfig list

 hci0:  Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: F0:03:8C:F3:22:5E  ACL MTU: 1024:8  SCO MTU: 50:8
        UP RUNNING 
        RX bytes:4165524 acl:417 sco:3409 events:569074 errors:0
        TX bytes:451525561 acl:528746 sco:1597 commands:40234 errors:0
```